# Cant import Firebase in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic 2. I am unable to use firebase import in ionic 2.

error

```
 Unused import: 'firebase'
 import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
 import firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: its an used import warning.. cant you use the firebase object?

Comment: i have already used firebase object, but its not working

Comment: you need to add the relevant code and any error msg you get..

Comment: `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

Answer (score 1):

You should install npm package before and import the firebase module in your app.module.ts

**Installation:**

```
npm install --save ng2-firebase
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
```

**app.module.ts imports**

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the installation process with npm install, you should probably import some other libraries from firebase that will be needed.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
};

@NgModule({
  ......
  ,
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
  ],
.....
})
```

The firebaseConfig contains the info from your firebase setup at: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/ in one of your projects.

**component.ts**

```
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, db: AngularFireDatabase, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {
        this.users = db.list('/users');
    }

......

}
```

In your component you will need the FirebaseListObservable to get your data from firebase. You need "observable", so that the list is always updated (o.g. Live score etc). And the AngularFireDatabase is needed to access firebase.

You can check this starter-kit: https://github.com/Temeteron/ionic2-firebase-starter-kit for more information.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run npm as an administrator and install with

> npm install --save ng2-firebase